# Записать результат парсинга лога в БД

Tags: python, sql

Передо мной поставили  задачу распарсить лог файл OpenVPN и вывести информацию о сессиях пользователей:

| username | connected timestamp | disconnected timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 2023-06-19 12:28:01 | 2023-06-19 13:11:17 |

Задачу я решил, но возник вопрос.

Уверен, что парсинг логов это довольно распространённая задача и вы с ней уже сталкивались,  основываясь на вашем опыте, как правильнее писать информацию в базу данных:

1. обрабатывать лог и сохранять сразу в формате

| username | connected timestamp | disconnected timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 2023-06-19 12:28:01 | 2023-06-19 13:11:17 |
| user2 | 2023-06-19 23:11:32 | 2023-06-20 00:41:38 |

или

2. писать в БД строку о каждом подключении / отключении

| username | timestamp | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 2023-06-19 12:28:01 | connected |
| user1 | 2023-06-19 13:11:17 | disconnected |
| user2 | 2023-06-19 23:11:32 | connected |
| user2 | 2023-06-20 00:41:38 | disconnected |

и потом приводить к нужному мне виду?

Comment: Парсинг лога должен выполняться по принципу "строка лога - запись в таблице". То есть ты просто изменяешь тип хранения данных, но никак не меняешь сами данные. А дальше уже из них запросом получай любые виды, какие нужны - на лету или сохраняя в другие таблицы.